# How to copy an object without referencing to it?

Tags: python, object, copy

I'm not sure if my title is correct for what I'm looking for, but I think that the referencing is the problem.

I have a Reader object through which I can loop:

```
msrun = pymzml.run.Reader(mzmlFile)
for feature in msrun:
    print feature['id']
```

With this code I get the id's, starting at 1, of all the features in msrun. However, I need to loop through the code first and get all the keys that I want and put them in a list, like this:

```
def getKeys(msrun, excludeList):
    spectrumKeys = []
    done = False
    for spectrum in msrun:
        if done:
            break
        if spectrum['ms level'] == 2:
            for key in spectrum:
                if key not in excludeList and not key.startswith('MS:'): 
                    done = True
                    spectrumKeys.append(key)
            spectrumKeys.extend(spectrum['precursors'][0].keys())
            precursorKeys = spectrum['precursors'][0].keys()
            break
        return spectrumKeys, precursorKeys
```

However, if I would run this code:

```
msrun = pymzml.run.Reader(mzmlFile)
specKeys, precursKeys = getKeys(msrun, ['title','name'])
for feature in msrun:
    print feature['id']
```

it starts of at the id that hasn't been in the loop in getKeys() (it starts at 11 instead of 1). So I guess  pymzml.run.Reader() works like a generator object. So I tried copying the object. First I tried

```
copyMsrun = msrun
specKeys, precursKeys = getKeys(copyMsrun, ['title','name'])
```

But this gives the same problem, if I understood correctly because doing copyMsrun = msrun makes them point to the same thing.

Then I tried

```
import copy
copyMsrun = copy.copy(msrun)
```

But I still had the same problem. I used copy.copy instead of copy.deepcopy because I don't think that the Reader objects contains other objects, and when I try deepcopy I get

```
TypeError: object.__new__(generator) is not safe, use generator.__new__().
```

So how **do** I copy an object so that looping through one doesn't affect the other? Should I just do

```
msrun = pymzml.run.Reader(mzmlFile)
copyMsrun = pymzml.run.Reader(mzmlFile)
```

?

---

Edit:
On Ade YU's comment, I tried that too but when I do

```
spectrumList = []
for spectrum in msrun:
    print spectrum['id']
    spectrumList.append(spectrum)

for spectrum in spectrumList:
    print spectrum['id']
```

The first print gives me 1-10, but the second print give me ten times 10

Comment: You may pick as much info as you need in the first loop and store them in some basic data structure, which you can easily manipulate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the publication of pymzML and the documentation, it is clear that this "pathologically design" is done on purpose. Initializing thousands of spectrum objects will create a huge computational overhead, memory and cpu cycle wise that are simply not needed. Normally, parsing large sets of mzML naturally calls for analyze-while-parsing approach rather then collecting everything one needs to analyze later.

Having said this, pymzML still offers the function to "deep copy" the spectrum simply by calling spectrum.deRef(). The advantage by using this function is that all unnecessary data will be stripped prior copying, hence offering smaller objects. [pymzML deRef](http://pymzml.github.com/spec.html?highlight=deref#spec.Spectrum.deRefhttp://pymzml.github.com/spec.html?highlight=deref#spec.Spectrum.deRef)

```
  run = pymzml.run.Reader(file_to_read, MS1_Precision = 5e-6, MSn_Precision = 20e-6)
  for spec in run:
   tmp = spec.deRef()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're dealing with a pathologically designed class.  There are some serious flaws in the library you are using, especially the part where the iterator yields the same object over and over again.

You'll probably need to copy the output of the iterator, like this:

```
objs = [copy.deepcopy(obj) for obj in pymzml.run.Reader(mzmlFile)]

for obj in objs:
    # do something
for obj in objs:
    # do something
```

If that doesn't work, you need to find whoever wrote the library and confiscate their computer.

Comment: this does work, but is considerably slower than

msrun = pymzml.run.Reader(mzmlFile)
copyMsrun = pymzml.run.Reader(mzmlFile)

for obj in copyMsrun:
     # do something
for obj in msrun:
     # do something

So I'm using that.

Answer (score 2):

Try `itertools.tee`, which gives you independent iterators. If this doesn't work, you are probably in trouble, because the objects yielded by your generator depend on some external state, (`id` =  number of objects yielded so far?), and there is no way to automatically help in that situation. `deepcopy` is your best bet, but if that doesn't work, you'll have to write your own class that captures alle the info from the `spectrum` objects.

```
spectrumList = []
for spectrum in msrun:
    spectrumList.append(MySpectrum(spectrum))
```

or the shorter variant

```
spectrums =  list(map(MySpectrum(msrun)))
```

You'll need something like

```
class MySpectrum:
    def __init__(self, spectrum):
        self.id = spectrum.id
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for simplicity I'm going to do it in the way as I commented on Dietrich's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) module to assign them without pointing to the same object

```
from copy import deepcopy
myq=deepcopy(transq)
```

Comment: As I stated in my post, my object doesn't have objects in it and deepcopy gives an error.